# Data did n't load on android app using firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I created an app using firebase on android studio.There is a searchview will appear after authentication with mobile otp. When user search on search view it will filter the results and goes to a recyclerview and so on. At the first time launch of activity(ie.,home activity after auth) app works perfectly.

But my problem is my app didn't load data after some time later.Also other fields including searchview also didn't work. Also,App works after logout and sign in again to the app after happened this problem.

Anybody know how to fix it?

My code is

```
public class FragmentHome extends Fragment {
private SearchView search;
View v;
DatabaseReference dataRef;
private  FirebaseListAdapter<String> firebaseListAdapter;
ListView mListView;
private TextView text;
ArrayList<String> city=new ArrayList<String>();
private int i=0;
private String data,val,var;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
ProgressBar progressBar;

@Nullable
@Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment_home,container,false);
    if (container!=null){
        container.removeAllViews();
    }
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

progressBar= (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.search_pro);
search= (SearchView) v.findViewById(R.id.search);
search.onActionViewExpanded();
search.setIconified(false);
search.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
search.setQueryHint("Search Docter By City Or Department");
mListView= (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.mList);
mListView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

dataRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Docters");
adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), 
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, city);
mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
dataRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
@Override
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    data=dataSnapshot.child("city").getValue(String.class);
    val=dataSnapshot.child("department").getValue(String.class);
    if (!city.contains(data)){
        city.add(data);
    }
    if (!city.contains(val)){
        city.add(val);
    }
    search.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

 }
 @Override
 public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    data=dataSnapshot.child("city").getValue(String.class);
    val=dataSnapshot.child("department").getValue(String.class);
    city.add(data);
    city.add(val);
    city.add(var);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

}

@Override
public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
}
});
search.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {
    if (!text.isEmpty()){
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       adapter.getFilter().filter(text);
    }else{
        mListView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    return false;
}

});

mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long 
id) {
    String itemRef = (String) adapter.getItem(position);
    search.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mListView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    FragmentTransaction ft=getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    DocterList fragment=new DocterList();
    Bundle item=new Bundle();
    item.putString("item",itemRef);
    fragment.setArguments(item);
    ft.replace(R.id.activity_fragment_home,fragment);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    ft.commit();
}
});
}
```

Comment: Don't post the same question multiple times. If your question is not getting enough attention, edit it to make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: Ok..thanks for suggession